# AWS Lambda function cannot be triggered through wscat

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I am creating Lambda-aws with one function implementation inside index.js

```
console.log('Loading the calculator function');

exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
    console.log('Received event:', JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));
    if (event.a === undefined || event.b === undefined || event.op === undefined) {
        callback("400 Invalid Input");
    }

    var res = {};
    res.a = Number(event.a);
    res.b = Number(event.b);
    res.op = event.op;

    if (isNaN(event.a) || isNaN(event.b)) {
        callback("400 Invalid Operand");
    }

    switch(event.op)
    {
        case "+":
        case "add":
            res.c = res.a + res.b;
            break;
        case "-":
        case "sub":
            res.c = res.a - res.b;
            break;
        case "*":
        case "mul":
            res.c = res.a * res.b;
            break;
        case "/":
        case "div":
            res.c = res.b===0 ? NaN : Number(event.a) / Number(event.b);
            break;
        default:
            callback("400 Invalid Operator");
            break;
    }
    callback(null, res);
};
```

But when I trigger this function through cmd using wscat, using this json :

```
{ "a": "Number", "b": "Number", "op": "string", "c": "Number"}
```

**Can you please help me to get it work?** 
Also, I tried to read values a,b and c but I always getting an error

```
{"message": "Internal server error", "connectionId":"BBkxxxxxxx=", "requestId":"BBkxxxxxx="}
```

I am using the same function as AWS use in [this example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/simple-calc-nodejs-lambda-function.html). So how can I solve the problem, and how can I send parameters to Lambda function either from cmd or angular backend?

Comment: try `callback(null, "400 Invalid foo")`

Comment: Sorry but doesn't work either.

Comment: I also replaced to this but doesn't work either 
    callback(null, JSON.stringify(res));